# How to do string concatation to make a list

Tags: haskell

Let I have two string. Say, `"learn"` and `"haskell"`. How can make them list like `["learn","haskell"]`

Comment: What's wrong with `["learn","haskell"]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
makeListFromTwoThings :: a -> a -> [a]
makeListFromTwoThings x y = [x,y]
```

Edit: I am assuming you want a function that does this generically.  If you want to do this in the Haskell shell then it seems like nothing is stopping you from typing `["learn","haskell"]` directly.  If you are trying to solve some more general problem directly in the shell then let us know the details of that problem.

Comment: yes you are right, I need to pass two strings as a single parameter of list of strings.

Comment: You could just pass `[x,y]` as the parameter.  The snippets `(makeListFromTwoThings x y)` and `[x,y]` are interchangable.